# How to use LIKE clause in JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I have a table named orders and My purpose is getting all orders which ends with 2012. My date is VARCHAR and I'm using MY-SQL database. In a class, I run the following `JPQL` query and I got

`Syntax error parsing the query [select object(o) from Orders as o WHERE o.orderDate LIKE %2012], line 1, column 58: unexpected char [%].`

I tried with this,

```
public List<Orders> getOrdersInCurrentYear(String def) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select object(o) from Orders as o WHERE o.orderDate LIKE :def");
        q.setParameter("def", "%" + def);
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

How can I get the all orders that ends with 2012 using this method?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `LIKE` operator for  `DATE` AND `DATETIME` data type.

There are some function for date, month, year, etc. Most of the `Persistence Provider` supported.

```
FUNC('MONTH', date)
FUNC('YEAR', date)
```

For `eclipselink`

```
select object(o) from Orders as o WHERE FUNC('YEAR', o.orderDate) = :def
```

Parameter

```
q.setParameter("def", def);
```